# Arrange blocks by 2D property without overlap

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming

My app needs to show several buttons, without overlap, and preferably without scrolling or zooming. They must be big enough to poke with a finger and read the text. Button width depends on its text length, and the height is constant. The screen size is known.

Each button represents a food about which I know some nutritional information. I'll calculate a protein:carb ratio and a fat content, both ranging from 0% to 100%.

I want to put the buttons close to a position that reflects their nutritional content: e.g. protein-rich at the top, carby at the bottom, fatty on the right and lean on the left.  So cake would be bottom right and meats would be somewhere on the top edge.

Often, there'll be overlap and I'll have to nudge them away from each other.

The puzzle is to invent an algorithm for that nudging. The desiderata in order of priority are:

1) Readable and pokeable size, no overlap.
2) No scrolling or zooming required, although it'll happen when there are so many buttons that they could never fit on the screen even if we didn't care where they were.
3) Buttons should be close to where the user would look based on knowing the nutritional content of the food.

Incidentally, I'm using JS on a smartphone, not prolog or the like.

(There are some seeming dupes, but no solutions. One is about diagonal stalks, another just advocates throwing it at a game engine, but most are devoid of answers.)

Comment: What do you consider to be the objective here, something like "total displacement"? Or "sum of squared displacements" to penalize solutions that move 1 item very far away to make all the rest fit?

Comment: [Masonry or one of its related projects](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-masonry-isotope-and-packery) might provide useful hints, or even a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther [MArVL group at Monash University](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu.au/) does work on constraint-based layout work.  Some of their [software](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu.au/software/) might be applicable to your problem.

Comment: Indeed their libvpsc in adaptagrams looks like the ticket. Thanks!